# Why my Gradle is showing Read Time out after adding Realm Database

Tags: android, realm

I just add Realm Database in my Project. But now my Gradle giving me error "Read Time out"
Below I'm showing full error image.

I'm Following Realm Documentation as they mention but still getting Error.
Please help me I'm trying to resolve this issue but didn't get any single issue related to this

[image]

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.9.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'realm-android'
}


android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.model_farming"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.3.1'

    // Meow Bottom Navigation Bar -- Not to Update
    implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.32"

    //OTP PinView

    //Loading Bar
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'

    //Shimmer
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    // Lottie dependency
    def lottieVersion = "3.4.0"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    implementation 'com.evrencoskun.library:tableview:0.8.9.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on build.gradle(Module) , add (id 'kotlin-kapt') before (id 'realm-android')

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'realm-android'
}


android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.model_farming"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.3.1'

    // Meow Bottom Navigation Bar -- Not to Update
    implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.32"

    //OTP PinView

    //Loading Bar
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'

    //Shimmer
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    // Lottie dependency
    def lottieVersion = "3.4.0"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    implementation 'com.evrencoskun.library:tableview:0.8.9.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
}
```